# Create a multidimensional array from mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I was wondering how I get a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
array(
"wifi" => array(
16 => 499, 
32 => 599, 
64 => 699
),
"wifi+3G" => array(
16 => 629, 
32 => 729, 
64 => 829)
);
```

Out of a mysql table that looks like this:

```
id, model, grootte, prijs 
1,  Wifi,    16,     449 
2,  Wifi,    32,     549 
3,  Wifi+3G, 16,     499 
4,  Wifi+3G, 32,     599
```

Comment: Have you even attempted to do this yet? If so, could you post some code? (Hint: If not, take a look at PHP's manual for [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php))

Comment: You can't get a multidimensional array directly after querying, you have to iterate over your result and build it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use one or more fields from your DB results as the keys in the array:

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $arr[$row['somekey']][$row['otherkey']] = $row;
}
```